# Undefined reference to QMediaPlayer and QVideoWidget

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt-creator

Even though I declared **QT += multimedia multimediawidgets** in my .pro file I am getting error **Undefined reference to QMediaPlayer and QVideoWidget constructors, destructors and methods**, I included path in my .pro file to those files in /usr/include/QtMultimetiaKit like this **INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/QtMultimediaKit/**, but errors are the same, what else to try?

I am running Qt 4.8.6 and Qt Creator 3.5.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.3.

Comment: See [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/1357/newby-needs-help-building-qmediaplayer-example/4) where they comment a similar issue. Also note that in Qt5 you can just use `Qt += multimedia multimediawidgets`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add to the .pro file:

```
CONFIG += mobility
MOBILITY += multimedia
```